# why can't I install Magento 1.9 now?

Tags: magento-1.9

I'm trying to install Magento older version but it gives an error like below if I install Magento 2 it doesn't give any error:

```
Error in file: "C:\xampp\htdocs\magento1\app\code\core\Mage\Dataflow\sql\dataflow_setup\install-1.6.0.0.php" - SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'dataflow_session' already exists, query was: CREATE TABLE `dataflow_session` (
  `session_id` int NOT NULL auto_increment COMMENT 'Session Id' ,
  `user_id` int NOT NULL COMMENT 'User Id' ,
  `created_date` timestamp NULL default NULL COMMENT 'Created Date' ,
  `file` varchar(255) NULL COMMENT 'File' ,
  `type` varchar(32) NULL COMMENT 'Type' ,
  `direction` varchar(32) NULL COMMENT 'Direction' ,
  `comment` varchar(255) NULL COMMENT 'Comment' ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`session_id`)
) COMMENT='Dataflow Session' ENGINE=INNODB charset=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_general_ci

Trace:
#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento1\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Resource\Setup.php(644): Mage::exception('Mage_Core', 'Error in file: ...')
#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento1\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Resource\Setup.php(421): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->_modifyResourceDb('install', '', '1.6.0.0')
#2 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento1\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Resource\Setup.php(327): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->_installResourceDb('1.6.0.0')
#3 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento1\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Resource\Setup.php(235): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->applyUpdates()
#4 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento1\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\App.php(428): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup::applyAllUpdates()
#5 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento1\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\App.php(354): Mage_Core_Model_App->_initModules()
#6 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento1\app\Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#7 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento1\index.php(83): Mage::run('', 'store')
#8 {main}
```

Comment: Delete all tables in database and reinstall the magento

Comment: Did you create a new database before installation and use that?

Comment: yeah i create a empty database but not working